# admob ads not shown in android game made by unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, integration

anyone help me in integrating Admob ads for android game ?

from the unity editor console I see that the ads created and requested and shown and all works 100%
but not shown in the android device .. why

```
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
public class ads : MonoBehaviour
{
bool called = false;
void Start()
{

    if (Application.loadedLevelName == "gameplay")
    {
        interesRequest(called);
    }
    if (Application.loadedLevelName == "mainMenu")
    {
        bannerRequest();
    }
    if (Application.loadedLevelName == "levelScore")
    {

    }
}
void bannerRequest()
{
    BannerView bannerView = new BannerView("ca-app-pub-5443208681329246/6087569010", AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    bannerView.Show();
}
void interesRequest(bool call)
{
    InterstitialAd inters = new InterstitialAd("ca-app-pub-5443208681329246/7564302219");
    if (call)
    {
        if (inters.IsLoaded())
        {
            inters.Show();
            called = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        inters.LoadAd(request);
    }
}
void Update()
{
    if (called)
       interesRequest(called);
}
public void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (gameObject.name == "pause")
    {
        if (menu.bug)
        {
            called = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're calling request and show functions at same time. This is impossible to make request and show ads at same time. Make requests in OnStart() function, and when level is changed or whenever you want show banner or interstatial ad. Because they need some time to download ads.

Comment: thanks for your comment -
can I request the ad in a scene and show it in other scene ?
- and what is the max period to load ads (2 or 3 seconds) or what ?

Comment: I tried to implement what you say , and also not shows the ads

Comment: can you add your new code? you can request in a scene and show in other scene but you need to define ad as static

Comment: and also max period depends connection speed and type of ad ( video, interstatial, banner etc.) . you can also make request in Start function and in Update function you can write a code as if(isLoaded) {show ad;}. it will show the ad at the moment ad loaded.

Comment: guys , my codes is right 100%
-
according to unity console : the ads created , requested , loaded and shown successfully

-maybe AdMob blocked my account from receiving ads as I tested the ads too much(just impressions no clicks)